# How to change Default App in Dokku for Domain Host Name

Tags: digital-ocean, dokku

As a personal project I've deployed the Dokku Image on Digital Ocean and got everything working well. In fact it works very well as I've done it before, but I have a question on how I can change what "default" app the Domain Host Name points to.

**Here is my setup.**

1. I set up Dokku on Digital Ocean with the "Hostname" and "Virtualhost Naming" options selected. So basically this means that I have my own Domain Name being used to point to apps instead of the IP/Port. Lets assume my Domain Name is mydomain.com
2. I have 2 Dokku apps running in this Digital Ocean server. Lets call them **app-a** and **app-b**. As I enabled "virtual naming" these apps can be accessed like so.

   - **app-a**.mydomain.com
   - **app-b**.mydomain.com

All this works perfectly.

Now I notice that if I go to "mydomain.com" or "www.mydomain.com" in the browser it "defaults/redirects with masking" to "**app-b**.mydomain.com". My guess is that because **app-b** was the last App I set up NGINX has defaulted to this.

**So how can I change this behaviour, i.e. I need "mydomain.com" or "www.mydomain.com" to go to app-a instead?**

Thanks very much in advance.

Mark.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> By default, dokku will route any received request with an unknown HOST header value to the lexicographically first site in the nginx config stack.

I believe you can add root domain using `domains` plugin

```
# add a domain to an app
dokku domains:add app-a mydomain.com
```

---

**or**

You can also specify fully qualified names as the name of the app

```
$ git remote add dokku dokku@dokku.me:mydomain.com
$ git push dokku master
```

---

**or**

> Alternatively, you may push an app to your dokku host with a name like "00-default". As long as it lists first, it will be used as the default nginx vhost.

---

References:

- http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/application-deployment/
- http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/nginx/

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. I went for option 3 as it would send all unknown hosts to my main app. Thanks again!